# Is there anyway I can show the path the algorithm has followed in finding the element

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I'm new to python and I am trying to code breadth first search for a simple graph. I want to show how the algorithm traversing through the nodes to find the goal node. i.e., the path followed to reaching the goal node. I have the code for shortest path, but I want help in writing code for basic breadth first search for my assignment. Do excuse any noob mistakes or errors. Any tips and tricks for python would be a huge help too. Thanks!!

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['D', 'E'],
         'C': ['F', 'G'],
         'D': ['B'],
         'E': ['B'],
         'F': ['C'],
         'G': ['C']}
```

```
def BFS(graph, start, end):

    nodes = [[start]]
    explored = []

    while nodes:
        path = nodes.pop(0)
        current = path[-1]
        if current not in explored:
            neighbour = graph[current]
            for neighbour in neighbour:
                new = list(path)
                new.append(neighbour)
                nodes.append(new)
                if neighbour == end:
                    return new
            explored.append(nodes)
        print(explored)
    return "Couldn't Find"
BFS(graph,'A','F')
```

Expected output for this example should be `['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','C','F']`
The output I am getting is `['A','B'],['A','C']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting confused between return and print. 
note that arrays are mutable which means changing a related array will affect its value. If you want to make them immutably, you need to put array.copy() when assigning/appending it to another variable

the code is returning ['A','C','F']
however it is printing ['A','B'],['A','C']
if you want the return to be `['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','C','F']` you need to record the nodes from the last loop. Here is a possible solution

```
def BFS(graph, start, end):

    nodes = [[start]]
    explored = []
    previous_nodes=[]
    count = 0
    while nodes:
        count += 1
        print (count)
        print(f'explored is {explored}')
        print(f'nodes are {nodes}')

        path = nodes.pop(0)
        current = path[-1]
        if current not in explored:
            neighbours = graph[current]
            for neighbour in neighbours:
                new = list(path)
                new.append(neighbour)
                nodes.append(new)
                if neighbour == end:
                    return [previous_nodes,new]
            explored.append(nodes)
            previous_nodes.append(nodes.copy()[0])
        print(explored)
    return "Couldn't Find"
print('return is ',BFS(graph,'A','F'))
```

Note that there are many libraries with data structures that will make your work easier such as  numpy, and pandas

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got it now

Answer (score 0):

I am not *entirely* certain what your code does, but for a breadth-first search this is what I would do:

1. Outside of your function, create a list that will represent the 'path' the algorithm follows.
2. Append the start element to this list.
3. Have one of the parameters of your search function be this list
4. In the function, before your execute a recursive call, append the element that call will be examining to the list.

```py
def bfs(cur_node, explored_list):
    ...
    # Logic
    ...
    explored_list.append(next_node)
    bfs(next_node, explored_list)

explored_list = []
explored_list.append(start_node)
bfs(start_node, explored_list)
```

You can obviously use different parameters if that is how your logic works, but this is the general structure I would use.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!!